# Is it possible in excel to run match on 3 cells and return a value of "true" if the criteria is met?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to run a match on 3 cells and return a value of "true" if the criteria is met.

I have two seperate sheets (sheet 1 and sheet 2).

- sheet1 has a listing of ID numbers in column A and a listing of dates in column B
- sheet2 has a listing of ID numbers in Column A and Column B has the header true/false.

I would like to return value of true in sheet 2 cell B2 if cell A2's value is contained in anywhere in column B and the date value in sheet1 column B contains today's date.

Is this possible?

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,TODAY())>0`?

Comment: Better to show a sample data set with your expected outcome.